# Senior vs. junior employee and office layout

Tags: politics, offices, office-layout

I have a dilemma. In our current office arrangement two offices have opened up if I shuffle some people around.

I have two employees in my department that share an office. One has worked in his role for ~5 years and the other has worked for ~3 years. The less experienced employee primarily works as a software developer and is having trouble being interrupted constantly due to the office location. (it's right near our help desk)

The more experienced employee does not have as much of an issue getting interrupted.

However, the experienced employee also prefers not to move to the second office that has come available. If he stays in the office he is currently in I will have to move other, more transient employees, to share with him.

Should I be worried of the perception of the younger employee getting a private office yet the more senior employee has to share one? The scope of their roles and responsibilities are obviously different but I'm considering office politics as well.

Comment: This is hard to follow. I suggest differentiating between "office building" and "office/room." It's also not clear who is currently sharing what with who, and what the results would be

Comment: You should also ask more clearly: Is it appropriate to give an office to a junior employee instead of a senior employee, for logistical and preference reasons?

Comment: You could always explain your reasoning in a team meeting.

Comment: Is there some reason the current office has to be the one to put newer employees?

Answer (score 8):

> However, the experienced employee also prefers not to move to the second office that has come available.

He has indicated his preference. Inform him that it will mean sharing so he has a chance to change his mind, then go ahead. He can't complain if it's his idea. Some people prefer to share.